# Spiders and beetle on a dodecahedron.

Tags: contest-math

This was a question from this year's Simon Marais Mathematics Competition. I myself had no idea how to solve it nor did I find anyone who solved it.Any ideas please?

> Three spiders try to catch a beetle in a game. They are all initially positioned on
>   the edges of a regular dodecahedron whose edges have length $1$. At some point in
>   time, they start moving continuously along the edges of the dodecahedron. The
>   beetle and one of the spiders move with maximum speed 1, while the remaining
>   two spiders move with maximum speed $\frac{1}{2018}$ .
>
> Each player always knows their own
>   position and the position of every other player. A player can turn around at any
>   moment and can react to the behaviour of other players instantaneously. The spiders
>   can communicate to decide on a strategy before and during the game. If any spider
>   occupies the same position as the beetle at some time, then the spiders win the game.
>
> Prove that the spiders can win the game, regardless of the initial positions of all
>   players and regardless of how the beetle moves.

Comment: Oh gosh, I also participated in this year's competition. Brain was fried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions to the Simon Marais 2018 problems are available [at the competition website](https://www.simonmarais.org/2018.html). I only know of the official solution to the problem (I'd love to hear if there are any others) - the main idea is to make the fast spider mirror the beetle's movement via a reflectional symmetry of the dodecahedron, which forces the beetle to stay in one half of the dodecahedron.